# CSS2 alternative to text-wrap: none

Tags: css

I have an element in which I would like my line of text to never break, not even when the text is reaching the bounds. In that case I simply want the text to overflow, like if it was just one long word.

After some research I found that the CSS3 property text-wrap can do exactly this. But it isn't supported in any of the modern browsers yet. http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_text-wrap.asp

Is there an alternative approach I could use.

Comment: What about `word-wrap`?

Comment: `word-wrap` could have been useful. But the only values it provides are `normal` and `break-word`. No `none`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try [overflow](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/overflow) and [white-space](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/white-space)? They have fairly good browser support.

[**View them on JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/mqYr7/1/)

```
#overflow {
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: visible;
}
```

And as a suggestion for the future [I advise against using w3schools](http://w3fools.com/) as their data is often incomplete and sometimes even wrong. The MDN is a much more reliable alternative!

Comment: Oh sorry, I was typing too fast. I was thinking regular overflow (which defaults to visible in most browsers, anyway).

Answer (score 1):

Wrap you code in `<pre>` this means that your text is pre-formatted and will only line break when you have physically declared it DEMO http://jsfiddle.net/kevinPHPkevin/zcSFp/

```
<div>
    <pre><p>this is a long paragraph this is a long paragraph this is a long paragraph this is a long paragraph this is a long paragraph this is a long paragraph this is a long paragraph this is a long paragraph this is a long paragraph this is a long paragraph this is a long paragraph this is a long paragraph </p></pre>
</div>
```

Comment: note that most browsers will default a monospace font for the `pre` element.

Comment: nice solution. But I prefer jmeas solution, because it's pure CSS, and this is definitely a styling issue

Comment: yea, `pre` pretty much just adds `white-space: pre;` which is almost identical to `white-space: nowrap;` except that it preserves newlines.

Comment: I agree with Jules. Semantically, its probably not quite appropriate to use `<pre>` since its specifically for "preformatted" text, not just text that should stay on one line. Separate style from data!

Answer (score 1):

This is just one of the very, very odd things about CSS specification. The closest property to what you're looking for is `word-wrap`. It unfortunately doesn't have a value for no wrapping, but `white-space` does. Try adding this to your element:

```
selector {
    white-space:nowrap; /* Sets no wrapping */
overflow:hidden; /* Hides the text that overflows the container. */
}
```

You could also use the jmeas' solution to add ellipsis, for example.
Source: http://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/w/whitespace/